# davfs2 : Depends: libneon27 but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, davfs2

### When installing davfs2 on Ubuntu bionic, I have got the following errors:

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 davfs2 : Depends: libneon27 but it is not going to be installed

### E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Then I have to install previous version of libneon27 first to make it right.

sudo apt install libneon27=0.30.2-2build1

Comment: Is your system fully upgraded?   https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libneon27 shows 0.30.2-3~ubuntu18.04.1 is the current up-to-date package for 18.04 LTS, so you're either running a out-of-date system (in which case `sudo apt full-upgrade`) or something else you didn't tell us is at issue.

Comment: This happens actually in Vagrant by using ubuntu/bionic64 cloud image "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/current/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant.box" when first install davfs2. I suppose in this case we don't usually do "sudo apt full-upgrade".

Comment: Here is my Vagrantfile:

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/current/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant.box"
end

Comment: Have exactly the same issue. Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 5):

I assume this is indeed a known issue [confirmed bug 1826063](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/neon27/+bug/1826063)

For know I am trying to configure using an older release of neon27:

```
sudo apt install libneon27=0.30.2-2build1
sudo apt-mark hold libneon27
sudo apt -y install davfs2
```